# Can't access Samba share on new drive from Windows

Tags: linux, centos, samba

I have a Rocky Linux server, and I'm using NFS to share between two VM's and I'm also trying to get the same folder shared to my laptop using Samba. I have one folder sharing successfully with samba and I can access it, but when I try to access the second folder I get this error:

[image]

I've tried so many tutorials but nothing is making it work. The folder is hosted on a second drive on the VM which I've seen is possibly the problem but I've found no solution, if anyone can help I'd appreciate it.

Config file:

```bash
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    server string = Samba Server %v
    netbios name = rocky-8
    security = user
    map to guest = bad user
    dns proxy = no
    ntlm auth = true
    wins support = yes

[Public]
    path =  /top-secret
    browsable =yes
    writable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no

[samba]
    path=/top-secret
    comment =samba
    browseable = yes
    writable = yes
    guest ok =yes
    read only = no

[new-disk]
    path=/mnt
    comment=new disk
    browsable=yes
    writable=yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
```

When I changed the path to `/mnt` as apposed to `/mnt/new-disk`, it let me access the folder but none of the files were inside.

Comment: Have you tried checking the Samba smbd server's log messages?

Comment: @tylerlecho: Press the _**See Details**_ and show the description details about the error, please.